# Using valueForKeyPath on NSDictionary if a key starts the @ symbol?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, key-value-coding

I want to use `valueForKeyPath` on my `NSDictionary`, but the problem is that one of the keys is a string that starts with the @ symbol. I have no control over the naming of the key.

I'm having problems trying to create the key path as I'm getting a format exception, even when trying to escape the @ symbol:

**This works fine:**

```
[[[dict objectForKey:@"key1"] objectForKey:@"@specialKey"] objectForKey:@"key3"]
```

**However none of these work:**

```
[dict valueForKeyPath:@"key1.@specialKey.key3"]
[dict valueForKeyPath:@"key1.@@specialKey.key3"]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: So basically your dict objectForKey:@"key1" is an NSDictionaryObject too. And that dict objectForKey:@"key3"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you shouldn't be using @ signs with your key names if you want to use key value coding.

[apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html) for key names are as follows:

> Keys must use ASCII encoding, begin
>   with a lowercase letter, and may not
>   contain whitespace.

You'll have to find a workaround to reformat the key string whereever you're getting your keys from to be KVC compliant.

Comment: Ah okay then! I thought some form of escaping needed to happen but thinking about it, of course something starting with @ can't be KVC compliant! Cheers!

Comment: np.  it'll also save you a lot of headache when you use other classes and technologies that use KVC, like core data.

Answer (score 13):

Just to update this old question a little...

The reason that these:

```
[dict valueForKeyPath:@"key1.@specialKey.key3"]
[dict valueForKeyPath:@"key1.@@specialKey.key3"]
```

...fail is that any "@" symbols in a key path are interpreted as being [collection's operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html) as with:

```
[dict valueForKeyPath:@"key1.@sum.key3"] // returns the sum of all 'key3' values
[dict valueForKeyPath:@"key1.@avg.key3"] // returns the average of all 'key3' values
```

The nested key calls:

```
[[[dict objectForKey:@"key1"] objectForKey:@"@specialKey"] objectForKey:@"key3"]
```

... work because a single key is not processed as a key path.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no control over the naming, how about adding a category with a properly named key that simply returns/sets the weird key?

Comment: that's a good idea.  but given what KVC is supposed to do, i don't see how that is even necessary.  KVC is a practice of sorts to make naming getters and setters consistently so you can access properties.  so if you can't name a property with an @ sign in it, then you should never get into a situation where it'd be a part of a keypath either.

Answer (score 0):

I see that there are 2 ways

**Swizzle**

You can swizzle the `valueForKeyPath` on `NSDictionary` to remove the @ symbol, remember to account for @sum, @average, ...

**Override if you're using Mantle**

Override `+ (id)modelOfClass:(Class)modelClass fromJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)JSONDictionary` on `MTLJSONAdapter`, traverse all the keys and remove the @ symbol

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, the whole discussion here goes the wrong way Accessing entries in an NSDictionary via key paths - is simply not part of KVC protocol.

KVC defines how to **name** your **properties** of an object, so that KVC can work. an entry in an NSDictionary is not a property, and has no name. NSDictionary adds its bit of magic to the KVC-like behaviour, by "pretending" the keys of its entries are like 'properties' of the dictionary.

Alas, properties have different naming conventions and limitations than dictionary keys.

If you cannot force the dictionary keys to conform with KVC-supported property names - break your key paths, and use the accessors instead where in doubt.

That, I think, should be the safest way to go. KVC is generally a "nicety" being able to shorten your code - but it does NOT provide any functionality you cannot have otherwise (as you demonstrated yourself).