# Why does [dict valueForKey:@"@"] cause SIGABRT?

Tags: objective-c, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using valueForKeyPath on NSDictionary if a key starts the @ symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567850/using-valueforkeypath-on-nsdictionary-if-a-key-starts-the-symbol)

Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
'[<__NSDictionaryI 0x100110e00> valueForUndefinedKey:]:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key .'
```

Example code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"foo": @"bar" };

NSLog(@"foo=%@, qaz=%@", [dict valueForKey:@"foo"], [dict valueForKey:@"qaz"]);
NSLog(@"@=%@", [dict valueForKey:@"@"]); // SIGABRT
```

<s>This also happens when using `[dict objectForKey:@"@"]`.</s>

Even when the "@" key is defined it still causes `SIGABRT`:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"@": @"at-sign" };
NSLog(@"@=%@", [dict valueForKey:@"@"]); // SIGABRT
```

Why is this happening and how can I retrieve the value for the "@" key from the dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `objectForKey:` when trying to access objects in a dictionary, the `valueForKey:` and `valueForKeyPath:` methods are meant for KVC and have some restrictions for their naming. Using `[dict objectForKey:@"@"]` will work and return either `(null)` or `at-sign` for your examples.

Comment: Still a SIGABRT seems drastic :(

Comment: @pst Well, thats what happens if you don't handle exceptions...