# NSDictionary keys with @ symbol

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Like asked here before [Using valueForKeyPath on NSDictionary if a key starts the @ symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567850/using-valueforkeypath-on-nsdictionary-if-a-key-starts-the-symbol)

If i have to use NSDictionary with keys like "@ID" and "@Name" (Server side limitations,I have no control over the naming) how can i work around that? Right now the app just crash every time I'm trying to access to this kind of keys.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're doing, can you show the code where the problem is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated you cannot do this. To Paraphrase [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html) reg. Key format -

> Keys must use ASCII encoding, begin with a lowercase letter, and may
>   not contain whitespace.

So trying to have a key with `@..` as start isn't going to cut it. What I suggest you do is this - since you cannot change the way your backend sends the keys, you can control how those keys are represented in iOS. So Once you get the keys remove the starting `@` symbol and insert the rest of the string as key. Since `@` is constant across all keys, removing them from all keys should not affect cardinality of your dict.

Comment: Thans, but how can i remove it when i cannot access this keys? when i print [MyDict allKeys] the app crashes too.

Comment: before populating `MyDict` process your keys which you got from your server and then populate `MyDict` with the new keys... Is that clear?

Comment: Yes I'll do that, Thanks.

Comment: @ItayAmza, I think there is way to handle the situation at your side. check my answer, please.

Comment: I also experienced this issue when @ was used in the beginning of the key - not in the middle or end. The obvious solution was to use a string replace on '@' to e.g. '(a)'. When I tried to break it again with other "odd" characters, numbers, uppercase or lower, I failed.

Answer (score 0):

what if you try to convert the dictionary after you get it with the irregular keys?

the idea would be this, and **yes, it is thread-safe**:

```
NSDictionary *_dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value", @"@ID", @"value2", @"@Name", nil];

NSMutableDictionary *_mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSLock *_lock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
[_dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([_lock tryLock]) {
        NSString *_newKey = [key stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@""];
        [_mutableDictionary setValue:obj forKey:_newKey];
        [_lock unlock];
    }
}];

NSLog(@"ID : %@", [_mutableDictionary valueForKey:@"ID"]);
NSLog(@"Name : %@", [_mutableDictionary valueForKey:@"Name"]);
```

Comment: @ItayAmza, anytime, if you think it is useful, please don't forget to mark it. :)

Comment: I dont have enough reputation yet to vote and i did accepted @Srikar Appal answer, Sorry.

Comment: @ItayAmza, too bad. :)