# Why does NSDictionary freak out when we have @ symbol in its keys?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, key-value-coding

I am having trouble with `RestKit` when I had a JSON response with `@` symbols in the keys. After some debugging it seems the issue is happening in `__NSCFDictionary`

So I tried the following simple code:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"@key1", @"@key2", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value1", @"value2", nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects
                                                   forKeys:keys];
for (id key in dictionary) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [dictionary valueForKey:key]);
}
```

And I am getting the following error:

> [<__NSDictionaryI 0x618000268ac0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for the key key1.

Can someone please explain why I am getting this error and if there is any workaround?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use `@` in the keys in conjunction with `valueForKey:`. `NSDictionary` [has some documented but perhaps unexpected behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/valueForKey:) in that case: it strips the `@` and invokes `[super valueForKey:]` with the new key. That looks for the key *on the object*, not in the dictionary's contents. No such key exists on instances of `NSDictionary`, so an exception is raised.

You should in general use `objectForKey:` to retrieve values from an `NSDictionary`.

Credit must go to Ken Thomases for his comments below, correcting earlier versions of this answer.

Comment: Awww nuts, +1 to you because your answer ([which is detailed further in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670240/nsdictionary-keys-with-symbol)) is more correct than mine.

Comment: This is somewhat incorrect. As is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/valueForKey:) in the `NSDictionary` class reference, if you call `-valueForKey:` on a dictionary with a key starting with `@`, it strips the `@` and calls through to `super`. Effectively, it accesses the properties of the dictionary, rather than its key-value map. So, `[dict valueForKey:@"@allKeys"]` returns the same as `dict.allKeys`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @KenThomases; I've revised and also pointed this question at an earlier one that has a great description of the problem by vikingosegundo.

Comment: You're welcome, but your edit still doesn't get it right. `[dict valueForKey;@"@someKey"]` will not look for `@"someKey"` in the dictionary's keys and retrieve that value. It will only look at the dictionary's *inherent* properties — the things for which it provides getters. Basically, `-valueForKey:` in the non-dictionary case accesses the object's properties. `NSDictionary` overrides this behavior to instead look in the key-value mapping it maintains, via `-objectForKey:`. But it provides a bypass mechanism to get back to the non-dictionary behavior, using this `@` prefix.

Comment: Argh. Thanks again, @KenThomases. I would just delete at this point if the answer weren't accepted. I've re-edited.

Comment: No need to delete. First, the exact behavior of the `@` prefix with `-valueForKey:` was always a side issue. The thrust of the answer, to use `-objectForKey:` and not `-valueForKey:` because the latter treats `@`-prefixed keys specially, was correct. Second, that's what editing is for. ;)

Comment: Fair enough, @KenThomases; I'm a big proponent of editing. It's more that there's _already_ a good answer, by vikingosegundo (that got it right the first time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you copied the code of someone who uses valueForKey: instead of objectForKey: without understanding what each is good for.

objectForKey: is what you should use. It takes the key that you pass in, and looks up the value for that key.

valueForKey: is a highly complicated method that looks at the text in the key, and does all kind of complicated things, for example a key of @"@sum" will add up some values. If that is what you want, fine. If you want to look up a value, use objectForKey. It does what you think it should do, and is usually several times faster than valueForKey: anyway.

As a rule of thumb: If I asked you whether you should use objectForKey: or valueForKey:, and you don't know what the difference is, use objectForKey: